# can I create more than 100 recurring jobs when using Jobrunr OSS, if our Database has enough resource like memory, processing capability

Tags: java, jobrunr

can Jobrunr OSS support distributed job processing, more than 100 recurring job?. as per official document can create upto 100 recurring job (Depend on DB). suppose DB have capability to store and process more than 100 jobs then can I create more than 100 recurring job.

Answer (score 1):

I think only Jobrunr Pro can run over 100 jobs.